# Software to make text analysis of csv file

Tags: open-source, data-analysis, csv

I have a csv with thousands (+5k lines) of entries about reviews. Each line is a review about a specific subject.

I am looking for a software to help me to make an analysis about this data. What I mean is aggregate data about same topics, find relations, detect sentiment analysis, etc.

There is any open source software that can help with this sort of things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is - the combination of [python](https://www.python.org/)/[jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) and [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is excellent for this sort of thing.

- Open Source & Gratis
- Read large CSV files
- Lots of data analysis & visualisation tools
- Cross platform
- Lots of output options
- To detect sentiments in each review you are looking at a natural language toolkit such as [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/).

Comment: thanks but I am thinking about a more simple setup. I am not a data scientist.

Comment: @anvd your requirements are for a data scientist. Unless you can be a lot more specific on what your CSV content looks like and what you need to do I don't think you will get a "simple answer"